# LOW SIGNAL NOISE RATIO FFT

Tags: fft, dsp-core, snr

I am processing an audio signal with CS4244 codec at 24 bits and 48kHz. Every 2048 samples the FFT is calculated and its amplitude. 
Without input signal I get FFT values ​​close to 30dB. With maximum input values ​​(overflow) I get values ​​of 90dB, with a scale of 0 to 120dB. 
Why not get a dynamic range of 100-110dB as is logical in a 24bit process? 
Any ideas? 
Thanks.

Comment: PLEASE DON'T SCREAM IN YOUR TITLE!

Comment: some error comes from arithmetic that rounds

Answer (score 0):

Try using an input of a very pure sine wave at an exact multiple of 23.4375 Hz.  A sinusoid that is integer periodic in the FFT length will show a maximum magnitude FFT result for a maximum (for the data type) amplitude input.  Otherwise the energy of a non-saturating input will likely get spread into multiple FFT result bins, resulting in a lower peak magnitude.